# I need to solve .net OOM issue

Tags: .net, out-of-memory

I have an OOM issue. I tried to determine what caused the OOM Exception using WinDbg but I didn't succeed.

I have a windows form with an Infragistics ultragrid that loads 11000 rows. Each row drwaws a delete bitmap.  I can't reproduce it on many machines, but a client reported very often so I asked for a memory dump

I need help to go further.

I have a memory dump with size = 1.9 GB.

I followed the steps bellow:

.loadby sos clr

!threads

[image: threads]

!pe 3c61f7d0

[image: print exception]

!dumpheap -stat

[image: dumpheap stat]

it doesn't seem to be a type candidate for OOM

I ran  !dumpheap -min 85000 -stat to figure out which objects are using over 85k memory and I got:

Statistics:

```
  MT      Count    TotalSize    Class Name
```

0028cd20        1       438732      Free

Total 1 objects

!finalizequeue
[image: finalize queue 1]
[image: finalize queue 2]

Comment: Are you manually loading bitmaps?  If so, are you disposing of them?

Comment: private void ConfigureDeleteColumnOn(UltraGridBand band)
  {
   band.Columns.Add(DELETE_BUTTON);
  var delCol = band.Columns[DELETE_BUTTON];
            delCol.ButtonDisplayStyle = ButtonDisplayStyle.Always;
            delCol.Style = ColumnStyle.Button;
  delCol.CellButtonAppearance.Image = Resources.Resources.delete;
  }

Comment: The dispose is made on ultragrid but now it fails at load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was how I configured the Infragistics grid.
The answer is also documented at this link:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/56315.aspx

The code that cause OOM issue was :

```
private static void ConfigureDeleteColumnOn(UltraGridBand band)
{
    band.Columns.Add(DELETE_BUTTON);
    band.Columns[DELETE_BUTTON].EditorControl = GetDeleteButtonEditor();
}

private static Control GetDeleteButtonEditor()
{
    UltraTextEditor editor = new UltraTextEditor();
    EditorButton btn = new EditorButton
                        {
                            Appearance =
                                {
                                    Image = Resources.Resources.delete,
                                    ImageBackgroundStyle = ImageBackgroundStyle.Centered
                                }
                        };
    editor.EditorButtonClick += editor_EditorDeleteButtonClick;
    editor.ButtonsLeft.Add(btn);
    return editor;
}
```

This code force the grid to create a new bitmap for each cell.Having 11000 rows, the grid tried to create 11000 bitmaps and caused an OOM exception.

The solution was :

```
private static void ConfigureDeleteColumnOn(UltraGridBand band)
{
    band.Columns.Add(DELETE_BUTTON);
    band.Columns[DELETE_BUTTON].ButtonDisplayStyle = ButtonDisplayStyle.Always;
    band.Columns[DELETE_BUTTON].Style = ColumnStyle.Button;
    band.Columns[DELETE_BUTTON].CellButtonAppearance.Image = Resources.Resources.delete;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. How did you conclude you had an OOM issue? An exception? What exception? Debugger output ? What debugger output?
2. A memory dump of 1.9 GB is very large. This makes it likely that your OOM is caused by being out of memory..... before you shout there *are* other things which throw an OutOfMemory exception.
3. If there are no managed objects over 85k, then it is either unmanaged memory or a very large number of objects less than 85k. This could for example be a map, linked-list or tree or similar, or your own hierarchy of objects.
4. If it's Unmanaged memory the top candidate would definitely be the bitmaps. Loading 11000 bitmaps doesn't seem like a terribly good idea. I suggest you not do that - why not use something like an "x" or similar?

Also, what does `Resources.Resources.delete` do? It looks like a property `get` but does it load up the bitmap each time, or load it once and use the same one? If it loads it each time then ... don't. If it reuses it that suggests that the grid is creating a fresh one for each line, which it really ought not to.

Comment: Hi! I found this http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/56315.aspx . Another problem is that I can't reproduce it on my machines

Comment: @DanNick are the machines you targeting 32bit, and your dev machine 64? 1.9GB sounds suspiciously like the 2GB limit in win32.